# Encoding.com watch folders notifications

Tags: video-encoding

We are using Encoding.com's watch folders to process videos from our Amazon S3 bucket.

It works fine but we have problems with the notifications. We want it to run a script in our server to update the video status in our DB and delete the original video file from S3. In the watch folder notification field we insert the script URL (http://www.domain.com/autocomplete/encoding-confirm/) but it never runs. When using the URL in my browser it runs fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was actually running, but since the notification is a returning NULL the PHP script fails to run.

Opened a new thread to see if anyone knows why this could be returning NULL.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739500/encoding-com-notifications-returning-null

Answer (score 1):

The notifications are most likely being sent in a POST request, but if it works when you hit the URL with your browser it probably means your script is listening for a GET request.

Comment: How can I test if my server is listening to POST requests properly? Is there a tool for that?

Comment: I tested it using FF's HTTP Resource Test plugin and it works fine with GET and POST requests.